# Is my question fit for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope

**Update: I recently edited the question and fixed a lot of problems with it. Now the following is pretty irrelevant**

**Update 2: My post is deleted again...**

I recently posted a question and it got some downvotes, so I reviewed the Stack Overflow help center and didn't seem to find anything that could be the reason my question was downvoted.

My question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893185/will-using-synchronous-functions-in-an-async-project-have-any-performance-drop

### The material I reviewed:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

1. My question was a specific programming problem, so I think I'm fine there
2. Not for debugging. Not for a simple error. Not a recommendation. Nothing about hardware. Nothing about legal things. Nothing about networking.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

1. Not every question will be equally valid
2. My answer isn't in the question
3. It's not an open hypothetical question.
4. Although it's a subjective question, its answers will most likely have the following

   - It will explain if using Pymongo in an async project will cause issues
   - Won't have short answers

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: There are two levels of quality control. The on-topic and don't ask pages are about the first level of quality control; what is allowed in or not. After that comes the second layer of quality control: quality voting. Even though a question is on-topic, that does not imply the question is useful. The pages you refer to are not going to explain to you when a post may receive up or downvotes.

Comment: Note that while questions about performance can be on-topic, they're rarely good, since most times the best answer is "measure it for your own setup", as the results may depend on memory speed, system speed, number of cores, your compiler, etc.

Comment: @ErikA I edited my question (I am a bit late to this because of writers block and things) and it’s still subjective, but follows the 6 rules of a good subjective question.

Answer (score 9):

It is not fit for Stack Overflow, as "fast enough" is [subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). We require a concrete problem to solve, or an objective performance metric to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After a while of thinking and trying to fix my post, I believe I did so. Although it is still subjective, I made it fit the 6 rules of a good subjective question [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Hey, I'm a bit confused (sorry), why did you vote for my question to be deleted? What was wrong with it? I thought I fixed the problems with it.

Comment: You are still fundamentally asking "if I should", and expecting *us* to come up with the pros and cons of each option. My take is that, as in the help page I linked, there is "no actual problem to be solved here". The blog post you link is from 2010 and policy has changed a fair bit over the years. Of course, others are welcome to disagree with me; the interpretation of policy is mostly a matter of community consensus.

Comment: Aside from that, my recommendation is to come up with a toy example of a problem in the same domain, **try doing it both ways**, and see what you like better. Which way is the code more understandable? Is the performance acceptable? Aside from that, consider doing [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to ensure that you understand the **purpose** of moving to an async model. (Topics to consider: 1) *what is your proposed alternative*? Specifically, does it involve *other* ways to achieve concurrency, such as threading? Do you *need* concurrency?)

Comment: (Hint: for a non-trivial web app - in the broad sense - you almost certainly need concurrency. Think about what happens if more than one person wants to use the bot at the same time. How long does the bot need in order to generate typical responses?)

Comment: If I wanted to fix this question (As it is the only thing keeping me from being un-question banned), what should I do? I've tried editing this question ten times and none of those seem to have worked. What are the new policies on subjective questions, and why is it still linked on "How to ask"? (Thx for responding btw)

Comment: It's not so much that policy has changed (the link in my answer here is current), but that interpretations from 12 years ago aren't necessarily in accordance with how people today will understand it. The site is not curated (nor moderated) by a computer program, but by humans, who have their own ideas about what individual words mean.

Comment: I don't think there's a meaningful question here that would be appropriate for the site (maybe something like "why would I need to write async code?" or "what problems does concurrency solve?", but those sound like duplicates). I agree that the question ban system is poorly thought out and can be absurdly harsh at times. Unfortunately, the Meta community is not in control of it.

Answer (score 5):

The fundamental problem to finding a definitive answer to your question is simple: **how much data are you *actually* dealing with here?**

Dealing with performance matters when you're talking about dealing with lots and lots of real data, or lots and lots of real processing.  In this scenario, your question addresses a *hypothetical* scenario in which you select a specific library and want to know how to mitigate a *hypothetical* pause if it's processing some specific workload.

We don't have a way to answer this definitively given that, depending on *how* you're interacting with MongoDB/PyMongo, you may or may not observe any real measurable performance hits.  You also don't describe how you're interacting with it, but you're also in a situation where you're unable to since you're still in the early building phase.

Ultimately, a question in regards to application performance *can* be accepted as on-topic here, but you're going to need to really provide some concrete scenarios that you're trying to troubleshoot.  We don't want to guess at this, and you wouldn't be satisfied with guess answers on hypothetical performance, and neither would future askers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After a long while of thinking and research (as I did not understand the topic thoroughly enough to create a question on it) I edited my post to fit the 6 rules of a good subjective question.